# Unable to set dateRange in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

this might sound tad easy, but I'm having troubles fixing it.

I have a jQuery UI datepicker with these settings :-

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#starting" ).datepicker();
      $( "#starting" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slide" );
      $( "#starting" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
  });
  </script>
```

Why does it still show the dates before today?

[image]

Comment: can you please try  `minDate: -1`  does it show you dates since yesterday?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio
I already tried it, doesn't seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring `defaultDate` seems to have fixed your problem.

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#starting" ).datepicker(  
            {
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                maxDate: "+6M",
                minDate: 0,
                hideIfNoPrevNext: false,               
            }
        );
        $("#starting").datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slide");
    });//ready
});//function
  </script>
```

This would show dates upto 6 months ahead starting from today.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks buddy.